# Basic probability question of combinations and permutations

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Can someone help me with this problem?

**A sack of fruit contains 3 oranges 4 apples and 5 bananas.
We select randomly 2 pieces of fruits. What is the probability that we obtain 1 orange and one apple if:

1. the 2 pieces are selected at the same time.
2. in succession with replacement
3. in succession without replacement**

How should I think of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. when the two fruits are selected at the same time - Total number of ways in which any two fruits can be selected in this manner is $\binom{12}{2}$. Number of ways you can select one orange and one apple is $\binom31\times\binom41=12$.
2. when the two fruits are selected in succession with replacement - Total number of ways in which any two fruits can be selected in this manner is $12^2$. Number of ways you can select an orange first and then an apple is $\binom31\times\binom41$. You can select an apple first and then an orange in $\binom41\times\binom31$.
3. when the two fruits are selected in succession without replacement - Total number of ways in which any two fruits can be selected in this manner is $12\times 11$. Number of ways you can select an orange first and then an apple is $\binom31\times\binom41$. You can select an apple first and then an orange in $\binom41\times\binom31$.

Hence the probability of getting an orange and an apple in the three cases will be $\frac{12}{\binom{12}2}=2/11$, $\frac{12\times 2}{12^2}=1/6$, $\frac{12\times 2}{12\times 11}=2/11$, respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I corrected it.